# Wierd Factorization of Matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, factoring

Let $A,B$ be matrices and $c,d,X$ be vectors...
Can I find a vector $e$ and a Matrix $C$ such that
$$
A(X-c) + c + B(X-d) +d = C(X-e) +e?
$$
It seems so simple but I cannot solve it... I've tried a few tricks and the furthest I have seem to have gotten to is to reduce the problem to solving for:
$$
(A+B)(X- (c+d)) +Ad +Bc +c +d
...
$$
However this does not seem to lead anywhere but down the rabbithole..

Comment: Choose $C$ without eigenvalue 1.  Then $C - 1$ is surjective, so that $e$ can be found as desired.

Comment: (Or maybe you don't mean these matrices to be square …?)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation as $(C-I)(X-e)=v:=A(X-c) + c + B(X-d) +d-X$. You are essentially asking that given a vector $v$, whether there exists a matrix $M\,(=C-I)$ and a vector $x\,(=X-e)$ such that $Mx=v$. Clearly, you may just pick $x=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ and any matrix $M$ whose first column is $v$.